# Least squares for y = ax+b model

Tags: python

I am trying to carry out a least squares fit in python. My model is y = ax+b and I have 2 lists of data each with 300 elements. My code is as follows:

```
xdata = np.array(time1_list)
ydata = np.array(phi1_list)

x_lin = np.linspace(0, xdata.max(), 10)


# Initial guess.
x0    = np.array([6, 5])

w = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, x0)
# Model
y_model = func(x_lin, w)

# PLOT ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Visualize data and fitted curves
pyplot.plot(xdata, ydata, "ko", label="Data")
pyplot.plot(x_lin, y_model, "k--", label="Fit")
pyplot.title("Least squares regression")
pyplot.legend(loc="upper left")
```

I keep getting the following error:

return func(xdata, *params) - ydata

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'

I have tried various methods to get this working but none seem to work. I am trying to get the best fitting values for a and b that fit the model closest using the least squares fit function, curve_fit.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This code is not complete and cannot run. The error seems likely to be in the missing part.

Comment: Can't tell without seeing your `func` definition, but based on the error, your `func` function is returning `None` or is missing the `return` statement.

Comment: Yes, sorry, here is my func:

Comment: def func(x, a, b):
   y = a*x + b
   return y

Comment: I am now getting the following error: leastsq() got multiple values for argument 'x0'

Answer (score -2):

Change `y_model = func(x_lin, w)` to `y_model = func(x_lin, *w[0])`

Comment: I have but unfortunately still get the same error